# How can i debug journey emails which include Ampscript from a Salesforce Data Event?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I think the subjectline says it all. Is there a possibility to debug my journey emails if my ampscript (which includes Salesforce Data Event) is working properly?

For example:

```
%%[
VAR @ReferenceNumber

SET @ReferenceNumber = Application__c:Vacancy__r:Reference_Number__c

IF NOT EMPTY (@ReferenceNumber) THEN
Show content
ENDIF

]%%
```

It looks like this code with Salesforce Data can only be tested after the journey is live. Does someone has a solution to test this without going live?

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest adding a record in the Journey Builder Data Extension, with data which will eventually arrive from the connector. This can be done in Contact Builder, where the Journey Builder Data Extensions can be found in the root folder.

Name of the Data Extension can be found on the Entry Event, once the journey is saved: 
[image: Entry event]

Go to the records tab in the Data Extension, and click the Add Record button. Once you have added one or more records, you will then be able to preview the specific email in content builder, using this Data Extension.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know that, but this is not testing the Salesforce data event. this is testing a automation which fills a Data Extension.